# Prove that $\sum ^n_{i=1 }(-1)^{i-1}F_{2i}=(-1)^{n+1}F_nF_{n+1}$by inductiProve that $F_0-F_2+F_4-F_6+F_8-.....=(-1)^{n+1}F_nF_{n+1}$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Prove that $\sum ^n_{i=1 }(-1)^{i-1}F_{2i}=(-1)^{n+1}F_nF_{n+1}$by induction

my attempt:

for $n=1$ LHS=RHS=1

suppose this is true for $n$

i.,e $F_2+F_4-F_6+F_8-.....+(-1)^{n-1}F_{2n}=(-1)^{n+1}F_nF_{n+1}$

now we have to prove for $n+1$

so consider $F_2+F_4-F_6+F_8-.....+(-1)^{n-1}F_{2n}+(-1)^nF_{2n+2}=(-1)^nF_nF_{n+1}+(-1)^nF_{2n+2}$ ???

how to we processed from here

Answer (score 1):

We shall use induction to prove that

> $F_0-F_2+F_4-F_6+\cdots+(-1)^{n}F_{2n} = (-1)^n F_n F_{n+1}$

The base case $N=0$ is easy since both sides are $0$.

For the induction step, we use [d'Ocagne's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#d'Ocagne's_identity):
$$
F_{2n}=F_{n+1}^{2}-F_{n-1}^{2}=F_{n}\left(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}\right)
$$
as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
F_0-F_2+\cdots+(-1)^{n}F_{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}F_{2n+2}
   &= (-1)^n F_n F_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}F_{2n+2}
\\ &= (-1)^n (F_n F_{n+1} - F_{2n+2})
\\ &= (-1)^n (F_n F_{n+1} - F_{n+1}(F_{n+2}+F_{n}))
\\ &= (-1)^n (-F_{n+1} F_{n+2})
\\ &= (-1)^{n+1} F_{n+1}F_{n+2}
\end{align}
$$